# Rails 5.2 Rspec 3.8 - Why is decimal model attribute converting to string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a migration like this:

```
class AddScoreToContact < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :contacts, :score, :decimal, precision: 4, scale: 3, default: 0
  end
end
```

When I try to test like this:

```
  contact = Contact.new(score: 0.5)

  puts contact.score.class # **outputs String**

  it 'is between 0 and 1' do
    expect(contact.score).to be_between(0, 1)
  end
```

The test fails unless I call `contact.score.to_f`

Why is it a string?

Test Output:

```
Failure/Error: expect(contact.score).to be_between(0, 1)
       expected "0.5" to be between 0 and 1 (inclusive)
```

**EDIT**

The model validations are:

```
 validates :score, presence: true
 validates :score, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0,
                                   less_than_or_equal_to: 1 }
```

Comment: Can you post the output of that test?

Comment: Does `Contact` define a `score` method that may be overriding the type casting? I cannot see any reason why this would occur otherwise

Comment: @engineersmnky Good question, but sadly no. The actual attribute name is data_integrity_score and it's only just been added by that migration. I called it score in the question to reduce 'noise'

Comment: what database ?

Comment: The only reason I can see for this is that you are using a database that does not support the decimal type (i.e. sqlite) and the adapter is converting it to a string

Comment: Good thinking but we are using Postgres, which supports decimals. So still a mystery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to drop the database, recreate it and then run the migration again. After that, it was no longer being converted to a string.

It is strange that this should fix the issue given that the test does not touch the database at all (it uses `new` and not `create` to create the object under test).

I can only conclude that in the process of working on this the test database ended up in an inconsistent state and somehow this was leaking into the test.